# PHP isn't actually executing

Tags: php

I have the code below and when I try to open the page I get the message

"; } // Close the database connection mysql_close($con); ?>

As you can see I closed it.  Can someone please help me.  Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Retrieve data from database </title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

$host='localhost';
$user='xxxxx';
$pass='xxxxx';
$database='xxxxx';

// Connect to database server
$con=mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die (mysql_error ());

// Select database
mysql_select_db($database) or die(mysql_error());

// SQL query
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM contact_list";

// Execute the query (the recordset $rs contains the result)
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

// Loop the recordset $rs
// Each row will be made into an array ($row) using mysql_fetch_array
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

   // Write the value of the column LastName (which is now in the array $row)
  echo $row['lastname'] . "<br />";

  }

// Close the database connection
mysql_close($con);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: mysql_ is deprecated. see PDO/mysqli_

Comment: Just FYI, [you shouldn't use `mysql_` functions to create new code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting an error or suggestion to close your data base, what you are getting is your own code. This is a problem with your tags, or your quotation marks. please revise all

**UPDATE**

actually, your server is not running any php. 
It is reading everyting as a big tag starting at `<?php` and ending at the  `/>` that you have in the line `echo $row['lastname'] . "<br />";`

Probably your file hasnt the php extension, or your server hasnt php available, or something is not well configured

Comment: Thank you very much!  I forgot to add some packages on the server.  It is working now.  You were exactly right